# deployed on .meteor.com but it's always down. Please explain this error log to me

Tags: logging, deployment, meteor

**edit:** the image.js file has the following code:

```
var imageStore = new FS.Store.FileSystem("images", {
  path: "~/uploads"
});

Images = new FS.Collection("images", {
  stores: [imageStore]
});
```

I tried deploying an application to kirstenszoo.adopt.meteor.com. It's been down the entire time, and I know there's somethign wrong with the app (it doesn't say anything though when it's actually deploying). I tried deploying another app to this same URL and it worked fine. The log below is waht I got when I used the command "meteor log kirstenszoo.adopt.meteor.com". Can someone please explain to me what this log is  saying?

```
[Tue Aug 19 2014 05:05:16 GMT+0000 (UTC)] WARNING Error: FS.Store.FileSystem unable to resolve "~" in path
        at new FS.Store.FileSystem (packages/cfs-filesystem/filesystem.server.js:29)
        at app/collection/images.js:1:53
        at app/collection/images.js:9:3
        at /meteor/containers/a8817e39-6de4-7b34-0b31-8bdbe4e22e09/bundle/programs/server/boot.js:161:10
        at Array.forEach (native)
        at Function._.each._.forEach (/meteor/dev_bundles/0.3.38/lib/node_modules/underscore/underscore.js:79:11)
        at /meteor/containers/a8817e39-6de4-7b34-0b31-8bdbe4e22e09/bundle/programs/server/boot.js:82:5
    [Tue Aug 19 2014 05:05:16 GMT+0000 (UTC)] INFO STATUS running -> waiting
    [Tue Aug 19 2014 05:05:16 GMT+0000 (UTC)] ERROR Application crashed with code: 8
    [Tue Aug 19 2014 05:19:45 GMT+0000 (UTC)] NOTICE Starting application on port 30293
    [Tue Aug 19 2014 05:19:45 GMT+0000 (UTC)] INFO STATUS waiting -> starting
    [Tue Aug 19 2014 05:19:45 GMT+0000 (UTC)] INFO STATUS starting -> running
    [Tue Aug 19 2014 05:19:47 GMT+0000 (UTC)] WARNING             throw(ex);
                      ^
    [Tue Aug 19 2014 05:19:47 GMT+0000 (UTC)] WARNING /meteor/dev_bundles/0.3.38/lib/node_modules/fibers/future.js:173
    [Tue Aug 19 2014 05:19:47 GMT+0000 (UTC)] WARNING Error: FS.Store.FileSystem unable to resolve "~" in path
        at new FS.Store.FileSystem (packages/cfs-filesystem/filesystem.server.js:29)
        at app/collection/images.js:1:53
        at app/collection/images.js:9:3
        at /meteor/containers/a8817e39-6de4-7b34-0b31-8bdbe4e22e09/bundle/programs/server/boot.js:161:10
        at Array.forEach (native)
        at Function._.each._.forEach (/meteor/dev_bundles/0.3.38/lib/node_modules/underscore/underscore.js:79:11)
        at /meteor/containers/a8817e39-6de4-7b34-0b31-8bdbe4e22e09/bundle/programs/server/boot.js:82:5
    [Tue Aug 19 2014 05:19:47 GMT+0000 (UTC)] ERROR Application crashed with code: 8
    [Tue Aug 19 2014 05:19:47 GMT+0000 (UTC)] INFO STATUS running -> waiting
    [Tue Aug 19 2014 05:44:13 GMT+0000 (UTC)] INFO STATUS waiting -> starting
    [Tue Aug 19 2014 05:44:13 GMT+0000 (UTC)] NOTICE Starting application on port 30293
    [Tue Aug 19 2014 05:44:13 GMT+0000 (UTC)] INFO STATUS starting -> running
    [Tue Aug 19 2014 05:44:14 GMT+0000 (UTC)] WARNING             throw(ex);
    [Tue Aug 19 2014 05:44:14 GMT+0000 (UTC)] WARNING /meteor/dev_bundles/0.3.38/lib/node_modules/fibers/future.js:173
    [Tue Aug 19 2014 05:44:14 GMT+0000 (UTC)] WARNING                   ^
    [Tue Aug 19 2014 05:44:14 GMT+0000 (UTC)] WARNING Error: FS.Store.FileSystem unable to resolve "~" in path
        at new FS.Store.FileSystem (packages/cfs-filesystem/filesystem.server.js:29)
        at app/collection/images.js:1:53
        at app/collection/images.js:9:3
        at /meteor/containers/a8817e39-6de4-7b34-0b31-8bdbe4e22e09/bundle/programs/server/boot.js:161:10
        at Array.forEach (native)
        at Function._.each._.forEach (/meteor/dev_bundles/0.3.38/lib/node_modules/underscore/underscore.js:79:11)
        at /meteor/containers/a8817e39-6de4-7b34-0b31-8bdbe4e22e09/bundle/programs/server/boot.js:82:5
    [Tue Aug 19 2014 05:44:14 GMT+0000 (UTC)] INFO STATUS running -> waiting
    [Tue Aug 19 2014 05:44:14 GMT+0000 (UTC)] ERROR Application crashed with code: 8
    [Tue Aug 19 2014 05:55:10 GMT+0000 (UTC)] INFO STATUS waiting -> killed
    [Tue Aug 19 2014 05:55:10 GMT+0000 (UTC)] INFO STATUS killed -> sleeping
    [Tue Aug 19 2014 07:58:33 GMT+0000 (UTC)] INFO HIT / 218.102.217.67
    [Tue Aug 19 2014 07:58:34 GMT+0000 (UTC)] INFO STATUS null -> starting
    [Tue Aug 19 2014 07:58:34 GMT+0000 (UTC)] NOTICE Starting application on port 14200
    [Tue Aug 19 2014 07:58:34 GMT+0000 (UTC)] INFO STATUS starting -> running
    [Tue Aug 19 2014 07:58:35 GMT+0000 (UTC)] WARNING             throw(ex);
                      ^
    [Tue Aug 19 2014 07:58:35 GMT+0000 (UTC)] WARNING /meteor/dev_bundles/0.3.38/lib/node_modules/fibers/future.js:173
    [Tue Aug 19 2014 07:58:35 GMT+0000 (UTC)] WARNING Error: FS.Store.FileSystem unable to resolve "~" in path
        at new FS.Store.FileSystem (packages/cfs-filesystem/filesystem.server.js:29)
        at app/collection/images.js:1:53
        at app/collection/images.js:9:3
        at /meteor/containers/a8817e39-6de4-7b34-0b31-8bdbe4e22e09/bundle/programs/server/boot.js:161:10
        at Array.forEach (native)
        at Function._.each._.forEach (/meteor/dev_bundles/0.3.38/lib/node_modules/underscore/underscore.js:79:11)
        at /meteor/containers/a8817e39-6de4-7b34-0b31-8bdbe4e22e09/bundle/programs/server/boot.js:82:5
    [Tue Aug 19 2014 07:58:35 GMT+0000 (UTC)] ERROR Application crashed with code: 8
    [Tue Aug 19 2014 07:58:35 GMT+0000 (UTC)] NOTICE Starting application on port 14200
    [Tue Aug 19 2014 07:58:35 GMT+0000 (UTC)] INFO STATUS running -> starting
    [Tue Aug 19 2014 07:58:35 GMT+0000 (UTC)] INFO STATUS starting -> running
    [Tue Aug 19 2014 07:58:37 GMT+0000 (UTC)] INFO HIT / 218.102.217.67
    [Tue Aug 19 2014 07:58:37 GMT+0000 (UTC)] INFO HIT /favicon.ico 218.102.217.67
    [Tue Aug 19 2014 07:58:38 GMT+0000 (UTC)] INFO HIT /favicon.ico 218.102.217.67
    [Tue Aug 19 2014 07:58:38 GMT+0000 (UTC)] INFO HIT /favicon.ico 218.102.217.67
    [Tue Aug 19 2014 07:58:41 GMT+0000 (UTC)] WARNING             throw(ex);
                      ^
    [Tue Aug 19 2014 07:58:41 GMT+0000 (UTC)] WARNING /meteor/dev_bundles/0.3.38/lib/node_modules/fibers/future.js:173
    [Tue Aug 19 2014 07:58:41 GMT+0000 (UTC)] WARNING Error: FS.Store.FileSystem unable to resolve "~" in path
        at new FS.Store.FileSystem (packages/cfs-filesystem/filesystem.server.js:29)
        at app/collection/images.js:1:53
        at app/collection/images.js:9:3
        at /meteor/containers/a8817e39-6de4-7b34-0b31-8bdbe4e22e09/bundle/programs/server/boot.js:161:10
        at Array.forEach (native)
        at Function._.each._.forEach (/meteor/dev_bundles/0.3.38/lib/node_modules/underscore/underscore.js:79:11)
        at /meteor/containers/a8817e39-6de4-7b34-0b31-8bdbe4e22e09/bundle/programs/server/boot.js:82:5
    [Tue Aug 19 2014 07:58:41 GMT+0000 (UTC)] ERROR Application crashed with code: 8
    [Tue Aug 19 2014 07:58:41 GMT+0000 (UTC)] NOTICE Starting application on port 14200
    [Tue Aug 19 2014 07:58:41 GMT+0000 (UTC)] INFO STATUS running -> starting
    [Tue Aug 19 2014 07:58:42 GMT+0000 (UTC)] INFO STATUS starting -> running
    [Tue Aug 19 2014 07:58:43 GMT+0000 (UTC)] WARNING             throw(ex);
                      ^
    [Tue Aug 19 2014 07:58:43 GMT+0000 (UTC)] WARNING /meteor/dev_bundles/0.3.38/lib/node_modules/fibers/future.js:173
    [Tue Aug 19 2014 07:58:43 GMT+0000 (UTC)] WARNING Error: FS.Store.FileSystem unable to resolve "~" in path
        at new FS.Store.FileSystem (packages/cfs-filesystem/filesystem.server.js:29)
        at app/collection/images.js:1:53
        at app/collection/images.js:9:3
        at /meteor/containers/a8817e39-6de4-7b34-0b31-8bdbe4e22e09/bundle/programs/server/boot.js:161:10
        at Array.forEach (native)
        at Function._.each._.forEach (/meteor/dev_bundles/0.3.38/lib/node_modules/underscore/underscore.js:79:11)
        at /meteor/containers/a8817e39-6de4-7b34-0b31-8bdbe4e22e09/bundle/programs/server/boot.js:82:5
    [Tue Aug 19 2014 07:58:43 GMT+0000 (UTC)] ERROR Application crashed with code: 8
    [Tue Aug 19 2014 07:58:43 GMT+0000 (UTC)] INFO STATUS running -> waiting
    [Tue Aug 19 2014 07:58:56 GMT+0000 (UTC)] NOTICE Starting application on port 14200
    [Tue Aug 19 2014 07:58:56 GMT+0000 (UTC)] INFO STATUS waiting -> starting
    [Tue Aug 19 2014 07:58:56 GMT+0000 (UTC)] INFO STATUS starting -> running
    [Tue Aug 19 2014 07:58:57 GMT+0000 (UTC)] WARNING /meteor/dev_bundles/0.3.38/lib/node_modules/fibers/future.js:173
                throw(ex);
                      ^
    [Tue Aug 19 2014 07:58:57 GMT+0000 (UTC)] WARNING Error: FS.Store.FileSystem unable to resolve "~" in path
        at new FS.Store.FileSystem (packages/cfs-filesystem/filesystem.server.js:29)
        at app/collection/images.js:1:53
        at app/collection/images.js:9:3
        at /meteor/containers/a8817e39-6de4-7b34-0b31-8bdbe4e22e09/bundle/programs/server/boot.js:161:10
        at Array.forEach (native)
        at Function._.each._.forEach (/meteor/dev_bundles/0.3.38/lib/node_modules/underscore/underscore.js:79:11)
        at /meteor/containers/a8817e39-6de4-7b34-0b31-8bdbe4e22e09/bundle/programs/server/boot.js:82:5
    [Tue Aug 19 2014 07:58:57 GMT+0000 (UTC)] INFO STATUS running -> waiting
    [Tue Aug 19 2014 07:58:57 GMT+0000 (UTC)] ERROR Application crashed with code: 8
    [Tue Aug 19 2014 07:59:18 GMT+0000 (UTC)] INFO STATUS waiting -> starting
    [Tue Aug 19 2014 07:59:18 GMT+0000 (UTC)] NOTICE Starting application on port 14200
    [Tue Aug 19 2014 07:59:18 GMT+0000 (UTC)] INFO STATUS starting -> running
    [Tue Aug 19 2014 07:59:20 GMT+0000 (UTC)] WARNING /meteor/dev_bundles/0.3.38/lib/node_modules/fibers/future.js:173
                throw(ex);
                      ^
    [Tue Aug 19 2014 07:59:20 GMT+0000 (UTC)] WARNING Error: FS.Store.FileSystem unable to resolve "~" in path
        at new FS.Store.FileSystem (packages/cfs-filesystem/filesystem.server.js:29)
        at app/collection/images.js:1:53
        at app/collection/images.js:9:3
        at /meteor/containers/a8817e39-6de4-7b34-0b31-8bdbe4e22e09/bundle/programs/server/boot.js:161:10
        at Array.forEach (native)
        at Function._.each._.forEach (/meteor/dev_bundles/0.3.38/lib/node_modules/underscore/underscore.js:79:11)
        at /meteor/containers/a8817e39-6de4-7b34-0b31-8bdbe4e22e09/bundle/programs/server/boot.js:82:5
    [Tue Aug 19 2014 07:59:20 GMT+0000 (UTC)] INFO STATUS running -> waiting
    [Tue Aug 19 2014 07:59:20 GMT+0000 (UTC)] ERROR Application crashed with code: 8
    [Tue Aug 19 2014 08:00:20 GMT+0000 (UTC)] NOTICE Starting application on port 14200
    [Tue Aug 19 2014 08:00:20 GMT+0000 (UTC)] INFO STATUS waiting -> starting
    [Tue Aug 19 2014 08:00:20 GMT+0000 (UTC)] INFO STATUS starting -> running
    [Tue Aug 19 2014 08:00:22 GMT+0000 (UTC)] WARNING             throw(ex);
    [Tue Aug 19 2014 08:00:22 GMT+0000 (UTC)] WARNING    ^
    [Tue Aug 19 2014 08:00:22 GMT+0000 (UTC)] WARNING /meteor/dev_bundles/0.3.38/lib/node_modules/fibers/future.js:173
    [Tue Aug 19 2014 08:00:22 GMT+0000 (UTC)] WARNING Error: FS.Store.FileSystem unable to resolve "~" in path
        at new FS.Store.FileSystem (packages/cfs-filesystem/filesystem.server.js:29)
        at app/collection/images.js:1:53
        at app/collection/images.js:9:3
        at /meteor/containers/a8817e39-6de4-7b34-0b31-8bdbe4e22e09/bundle/programs/server/boot.js:161:10
        at Array.forEach (native)
        at Function._.each._.forEach (/meteor/dev_bundles/0.3.38/lib/node_modules/underscore/underscore.js:79:11)
        at /meteor/containers/a8817e39-6de4-7b34-0b31-8bdbe4e22e09/bundle/programs/server/boot.js:82:5
    [Tue Aug 19 2014 08:00:22 GMT+0000 (UTC)] ERROR Application crashed with code: 8
    [Tue Aug 19 2014 08:00:22 GMT+0000 (UTC)] INFO STATUS running -> waiting
    [Tue Aug 19 2014 08:02:44 GMT+0000 (UTC)] INFO STATUS waiting -> starting
    [Tue Aug 19 2014 08:02:44 GMT+0000 (UTC)] NOTICE Starting application on port 14200
    [Tue Aug 19 2014 08:02:44 GMT+0000 (UTC)] INFO STATUS starting -> running
    [Tue Aug 19 2014 08:02:45 GMT+0000 (UTC)] WARNING             throw(ex);
                      ^
    [Tue Aug 19 2014 08:02:45 GMT+0000 (UTC)] WARNING /meteor/dev_bundles/0.3.38/lib/node_modules/fibers/future.js:173
    [Tue Aug 19 2014 08:02:45 GMT+0000 (UTC)] WARNING Error: FS.Store.FileSystem unable to resolve "~" in path
        at new FS.Store.FileSystem (packages/cfs-filesystem/filesystem.server.js:29)
        at app/collection/images.js:1:53
        at app/collection/images.js:9:3
        at /meteor/containers/a8817e39-6de4-7b34-0b31-8bdbe4e22e09/bundle/programs/server/boot.js:161:10
        at Array.forEach (native)
        at Function._.each._.forEach (/meteor/dev_bundles/0.3.38/lib/node_modules/underscore/underscore.js:79:11)
        at /meteor/containers/a8817e39-6de4-7b34-0b31-8bdbe4e22e09/bundle/programs/server/boot.js:82:5
    [Tue Aug 19 2014 08:02:45 GMT+0000 (UTC)] INFO STATUS running -> waiting
    [Tue Aug 19 2014 08:02:45 GMT+0000 (UTC)] ERROR Application crashed with code: 8
    [Tue Aug 19 2014 08:06:55 GMT+0000 (UTC)] NOTICE Starting application on port 14200
    [Tue Aug 19 2014 08:06:55 GMT+0000 (UTC)] INFO STATUS waiting -> starting
    [Tue Aug 19 2014 08:06:56 GMT+0000 (UTC)] INFO STATUS starting -> running
    [Tue Aug 19 2014 08:06:57 GMT+0000 (UTC)] WARNING /meteor/dev_bundles/0.3.38/lib/node_modules/fibers/future.js:173
                throw(ex);
                      ^
    Error: FS.Store.FileSystem unable to resolve "~" in path
        at new FS.Store.FileSystem (packages/cfs-filesystem/filesystem.server.js:29)
        at app/collection/images.js:1:53
        at app/collection/images.js:9:3
        at /meteor/containers/a8817e39-6de4-7b34-0b31-8bdbe4e22e09/bundle/programs/server/boot.js:161:10
        at Array.forEach (native)
        at Function._.each._.forEach (/meteor/dev_bundles/0.3.38/lib/node_modules/underscore/underscore.js:79:11)
        at /meteor/containers/a8817e39-6de4-7b34-0b31-8bdbe4e22e09/bundle/programs/server/boot.js:82:5
    [Tue Aug 19 2014 08:06:57 GMT+0000 (UTC)] INFO STATUS running -> waiting
    [Tue Aug 19 2014 08:06:57 GMT+0000 (UTC)] ERROR Application crashed with code: 8
    [Tue Aug 19 2014 08:07:13 GMT+0000 (UTC)] INFO HIT / 218.102.217.67
    [Tue Aug 19 2014 08:07:14 GMT+0000 (UTC)] INFO HIT /favicon.ico 218.102.217.67
    [Tue Aug 19 2014 08:07:14 GMT+0000 (UTC)] INFO HIT /favicon.ico 218.102.217.67
    [Tue Aug 19 2014 08:07:15 GMT+0000 (UTC)] INFO HIT /favicon.ico 218.102.217.67
```

Comment: Sounds like line 1 of `app/collection/images.js` is making a call to the `cfs-filesystem` package that it doesn't like because of the supplied path.  Can't really say any more without seeing the line in question- can you post it?

Comment: I'll add it to the original question via edit!

Answer (score 2):

It appears that you are using collectionfs's local filesystem storage. The problem is that the deployed app to meteor.com doesn't have access/availability to write to such a path. I ran into the exact same problem. My solution was to simply comment out or delete the path and I would also combine your two declaration's for simplicity. For the deployed app:

```
Images = new FS.Collection("images", {
  stores: [new FS.Store.FileSystem("images")]
 });
```

When running it locally use:

```
 Images = new FS.Collection("images", {
   stores: [new FS.Store.FileSystem("images", {path: "~/uploads"})]
 });
```

Answer (score 0):

The error indicates that it doesn't understand the `~` in the path you're supplying.  Implementation of tilde is server-specific as far as I'm aware, and almost certainly won't work if your path is being appended to anything else (and thus the tilde doesn't come first).  Whatever the cause, you can't use a tilde here.

Essentially, you need to express the path in a different way.  Have you tried just using `path: "/uploads"` and seeing if that works?

Comment: I tried that, it doesn't work. I looked through the whole app and some of the package files from the image uploader (which is probably the thing causing the problem here) uses ~/ as default. Not sure what to make of this. My friend also used this package for an earlier project and had the same uploading problem

Comment: Does it give the same error?  And does this app work locally?  Essentially, the tilde is just an alias to a path on your local machine, but the alias doesn't work when you deploy - you just need to work out what the full path should be so that it'll work on both.

Comment: Tried deleting the ~ in all the places it asks for ~/uploads path. It breaks everything,

Comment: It's a bit difficult to diagnose with that feedback - is it the same error? I'd concentrate on getting line 1 to work as this will enable you to work out what you need to do elsewhere.

Answer (score 0):

It will work if you change path to `path: "./uploads"` both on your local machine and free test meteor.com server. You will need however make sure your components are not hardcoded with `~/uploads`.

Also you may try `FS.Store.GridFS` to store your images in Mongo DB, check out the link:
https://medium.com/@victorleungtw/how-to-upload-files-with-meteor-js-7b8e811510fa

Pay attention that using GridFS may have some disadvantages like longer time of Mongo recovery process.